# Configurable Themes in React and Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, themes, less, antd

We are trying to develop a React app that allows themes to be configured once the app is built. We are using ant design, which uses less for styling. Once the build and shipped to the end-user, they can add a new theme by updating a configuration file (say a JSON file in public folder or serve configuration from the back-end).

We have already given a shoot to https://github.com/mzohaibqc/antd-theme-webpack-plugin/tree/master/examples/customize-cra. This approach creates JSON per theme, which consists of all the less variable values. We will share the JSON with the end-user, which can modify themes are per their needs. But the limitation here is that only colors are configurable stylings like font size, spacing is not.

Are we bound to use less for styling here as we need to modify ant design components also?
Is there any existing plugin or approach that can solve the problem?
If not, can someone please guide me on writing a similar plugin?

Thanks for the future help :)